# "performant" or "performance"?

Tags: vocabulary

> 5 Tips for Performant, Thread-Safe Java From ConcurrentHashMap

Why does this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/5-tips-for-high-performance-thread-safe-java-from?edition=357100&utm_source=Daily%20Digest&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Daily%20Digest%202018-01-23) use **performant** instead of **performance**? Are they any differences between these two?

Comment: Check out the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112743/what-does-performant-software-actually-mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference between these two words. The difference is that they're essentially different parts of speech. The word [**performant**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/performant) is an adjective while the word [**performance**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/performance) is a noun. In the link above, *performant* is defined as *working in an effective way*. I hear this word a lot used in the world of programming and technology. A performant piece of code is one that works with great performance. In other words, if you want your code to be performant, you should write it in a way that makes your code run fast and efficiently.

To make a long story short, the word *performant* is used to describe a piece of code or a particular piece of technology as working efficiently while the word *performance* talks about a task or operation seen in terms of how successfully it is performed or how successfully it operates.

You could say, for example, *5 performance tips*, but you wouldn't say *5 performant tips* because *a performance tip* means a tip for how to make things work with better performance while *a performant tip* would mean that the tip itself works with great performance. And that, of course, makes no sense. Likewise, *performant Java* means a piece of Java code that works efficiently whereas *performance Java* would mean a piece of Java code that has something to do with performance rather than being itself performant. Does that make any sense to you? I don't think so. That phrase, for all practical purposes, is pretty much meaningless.